# MDX with snowflaked dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have an ordinary `DimProduct` which has a snowflaked `DimPriceList` where I store for each `ProductKey` different prices for the products.

In a `MDX`, depending on certain product properties, I would like to display different prices for the products. The MDX would look something like this.

```
CASE 
WHEN [Dim Product].[Value Group].CurrentMember.MEMBERVALUE = '02' THEN
    CASE 
    WHEN [Dim Product].[Stock Account Nr].CurrentMember.MEMBERVALUE = 101 THEN
        ([Dim Price List].[Sales1])
    WHEN [Dim Product].[Stock Account Nr].CurrentMember.MEMBERVALUE = 102 OR  
            [Dim Product].[Stock Account Nr].CurrentMember.MEMBERVALUE = 103 THEN
        ([Dim Price List].[Valuation])
    ELSE
        0
    END
ELSE
    1 
END
```

How can I now access the current membervalue of the `DimPriceList`? I just get 'All' as result and not the actual value for the current member. I've also tried [Dim Price List].[Valuation].CurrentMember.MEMBERVALUE but with no success. Appreciate any sort of help or hints.

Comment: Is this snippet part of your _cube script_ ? When you try to use this logic in a subsequent `mdx` what does that expression look like - we need the whole context to understand why the 'All' member is being returned.

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You get the `[All]` member because it IS the default value. In absence of any scope, the engine bases it's calculation around the default member. If you want the output to change based on the *current member* of Product, you should attempt at creating a calculated member. Encapsulate the logic above into the script which chooses the requisite measure depending upon the current member. I am assuming you must be having `Sales1` and `Valuation` in form of Measure in your cube. If that is the case your calculated member should choose the requisite measure based on the `MEMBERVALUE` **or** you can employ

```
....
[Dim Product].[Stock Account Nr].CurrentMember IS [Dim Product].[Stock Account Nr].&[101]
....clause.
```

That said, you need to give some scope.